# How can i compare two DateTimeFields with current time

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

Event has two DateTimeField's and i need to compare them to the actual date time in a same method.

```
from django.utils import timezone

event_starts = models.DateTimeField(_("Event starts"))
registration_closes_at = models.DateTimeField(
        _("Registration ends:"), null=True, blank=True
    )
```

This is what i have tried, but it doesn't work. So what i need is: If event has been started or registration was closed user can not attend this event.

```
    def is_registration_open(self):
    now = timezone.now()
    passed_registration = now > self.registration_closes_at
    passed_start = now > self.event_starts

    if not passed_registration or not passed_start:
        return
```

And tried this:

```
def is_registration_open(self):

    if (
        not timezone.now() > self.registration_closes_at
        or not timezone.now() > self.event_starts
    ):
        return
```

Here is a fail:

```
'>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'NoneType'
```

When i compare only event_starts everything is working fine.

Thanks for help!

Comment: hint: what if date is null in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that `registration_closes_at` field is nullable, therefore you need to handle that case in the condition.

My guess is that you would like to ignore the `registration_closes_at` when it is null, so the condition would look like:

```
def is_registration_open(self):
    if self.registration_closes_at:
        # before registration closes
        return timezone.now() < self.registration_closes_at
    else:
        # before event starts
        return timezone.now() < self.event_starts
```

Even better option is to use annotation and check the condition on the database for better performance

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, Value, BooleanField
from django.db.models.functions import Now

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    can_register=Case(
        When(registration_closes_at__gt=Now(), then=Value(True)),
        When(event_starts__gt=Now(), then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    )
)
```